# Multiple c# SerialPorts seems to hang my application

Tags: windows, winforms, serial-port

I've an application in Windows forms that connects to 16 serialports. The structure I used for each one is:

```
private void Serial_CodeNip_15_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string S = Serial_CodeNip_15.ReadExisting();
    myProcess(S);
}
public delegate void del_myProcess(string stringa);
private void myProcess(string stringa)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        del_myProcess tmp = new del_myProcess(myProcess);
        try
        {
            this.Invoke(tmp, stringa);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // my code here
    }
}
```

Receiving data from barcode readers, works fine until more Readers (up 6 or 7) start reading at the same time. In this cases my application tends to hang and all readers denotes a difficult to catch data from serial input buffers.  Is this the correct way to read async data from serialports or there’s another simple way to do that. I noticed that working with few serialports there’s no problem.

Thank you in advance for helping

Comment: "denotes a difficult to catch data" is not an appropriate problem description.  Pay attention to what your UI thread is doing, you are pummeling it with invokes, passing only 1 or 2 characters.  Crystal ball says that it burning 100% core trying to do something useless with those characters like adding them to a textbox that has ever more text that never gets purged.  When it gets fire-hosed like that then it stops taking care of lower-priority duties.  Like painting and processing input.  Add logging to your program, log to a file, so you can see this going wrong.

Comment: Do as much processing as you can on the incoming thread and only invoke to the UI thread if you have something that must interact with the UI. (eg wait till all the relevant data from that scanner has arrived). Also `Invoke` waits for `myProcess` to finish before execution continues. Instead use `BeginInvoke`. And remove the empty try catch, if you have an exception you will want to know about it.

Comment: Sorry by my not so good description of the problem but I don’t know how to explain better.  The only thing I know is there’s no problem if I activate 4 o 5 serial objects but the app degrades a lot when more serial are active. Data I catch is 10 characters only and it is assigned to an only Text property of a control and used inside the classes as variables, without painting nothing.  16 objects work fine if reading events are not contemporary. When overlapping.  Thank you for comment.

Comment: Thank you for tips FloatingKiwi, I'll try to optimize mycode area.